# Javascript stops when add new objects dynamically

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to add new "li" objects that have some JS behind dynamically, but when i add them the JS in the added "li" does not work.

here's the JS: [JavaScript File](http://jsfiddle.net/Bookable/JM2An/)

and this is how i'm adding the new "li" :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search-bar').keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {

            addNew();

        }
    });

    function addNew() {
        var city = $('#search-bar').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("getWeatherSearch", "Index")',
            data: { city: city },
            async: false,
            complete: function (resp) {
                $("#rb-grid").prepend(resp.responseText);
            }
        });
    } });
```

The function in C# that i'm calling in the controller returns a string with the "li".

and just calling Boxgrid.init() does not help.

Comment: Do you have a particularly good reason why you're using `async : false` ?

Comment: Have you debugged the JS to confirm what is contained in `resp.ResponseText`?

Comment: @LeeTaylor sorry i retired it already, but this is not the problem....

Comment: @ledbutter yes, its containing what i want, even because he adds the LI but the JS of the LI stops working...

Comment: We'd also have an easier time helping you if you provided a fiddle with a small, complete example that demonstrates the problem (i.e. take the `ajax` call out and just try to `prepend` something to `#rb-grid')

Comment: @Vinicius I don't think LeeTaylor was saying that it was the problem. However, it is hard to justify syncronous calls in any situation. I think he was just pointing out that you should probably remove the async: false and let it be asyncronous as it is meant to be.

Comment: `when i add them the JS in the added "li" does not work.` what "JS in the added li"?  Were's that code?

Comment: Ok... I have LI html tags, containing the wheater temperature and i have a search bar, to search for other cities wheaters, in theory when the user press enter the site have to add a new LI tag containing the city that the user searched... the site is adding new LI but the new LI does not work but the old ones works perfectly, the reason is because i have to restart the JS, but i have no successfull in doing that.

Comment: @JeffShaver - Correct ;-)

Comment: @MattBurland maan, the JS is on the link....

Comment: @Vinicius I assume you mean your event handlers aren't working on the new li elements? This is common. You should try something like this... `$('#parentOfLiElements').on('click', 'li', function(ev) {}); Basically, you attach an event handler to the parent element and let the events from the li elements bubble up. It would also allow the new elements to work since the event isn't bound directly to the li elements themselves

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$('#parentofli').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
   $(this). whatever you want to do on the li
});
```

Whenever you want JS to run on dynamically inserted objects

When you have regular javascript on selectors everything gets binded when the document is ready. If you insert an element afterwards JS functions don't know that it exists and therefore it does not bind.

when you use the parent as the selector then the javascript binds to the PARENT itself and whenever you click in the parent it will go through each parent binded function and see if it matches